# VBA: Naming Multiple Charts Using For Each and With Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that generates two graphs using a `For Each` and a `With` statement. I would like to name both of these graphs based on their tab's name.

For instance I generate a graph from Sheet1 and Sheet2, and place them in those sheets, so I would like these graphs to be named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".

In my code, I first define the chart name as a string then I set the chart name variable equal to the worksheet names and lastly I set the `ActiveChart.Name` equal to the defined chart name variable. My problem is that I get an error when I run this code, for some reason VBA doesn't like how I name these charts. Any information that can help me resolve this problem is much appreciated. Thanks!

My code:

```
Sub Charts()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim sChtName As String

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
With ws
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:E6"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    sChtName = ws.Name
    ActiveChart.Name = sChtName
    ActiveChart.Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name
End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message and on what line?

Comment: Just curious.. why are you not inserting the chart directly in the sheet rather than creating a chart sheet and then moving it?

Comment: Don't you need inserting embedded charts? If yes, they are inserted in a different way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things

1. You cannot name the procedure as `Charts` in `Sub Charts()`. It will interfere with `Charts.Add`. Use something like (*for example*) `Sub AddCharts()`
2. You cannot have a second sheet with a same name. `ActiveChart.Name = sChtName` will give error as **name already has been taken**. You can use a variable to change the name of the chart.
3. No need of `With ws - End With` if you are not planning to use it.
4. `Sheets(ws.Name)`: Since you already have the object, use that.

For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddCharts()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sChtName As String
    Dim i As Long

    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
        Charts.Add
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("A1:E6"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
        sChtName = ws.Name & i
        ActiveChart.Name = sChtName
        i = i + 1
        ActiveChart.Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Also as an added precaution, Check if there is a sheet with the name `sChtName = ws.Name & i` before assigning the name to the chart sheet.